# List in Java not working

Tags: java, eclipse, list

I wrote a simple menu-driven list program where the user is given a choice like `1. To add an element to the list`, `2. To display an element at a particular index` and `3. To remove an element from a particular index`.
My source code complies correctly. But, when I run it, I am getting some weird errors which is hard to make out.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Menu {
List list = new ArrayList();
String element;
int choice;
int index;

public void tolist(){
    list.add("Rahul");
    list.add("Sam");
}

public void greet(){
    System.out.println("Welcome!");
    }

public int choice(){
    System.out.println("Enter 1 To Add An Element");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 To Display An Element");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 To Delete An Element");
    Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
    choice = S.nextInt();
    return choice;
}
    public void add(){
        /*System.out.println("Enter the Index Where The Element Is To Be Added");
        Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
        index=S.nextInt();*/
        Scanner P = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter An Element");
        element=P.nextLine();
        list.add(element);
    }

    public void show(){

        System.out.println("Enter The Index");
        Scanner S=new Scanner(System.in);
        index=S.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The Element At The Index " +index +"Is " +list.get(index));
        }

    public void remove(){

        System.out.println("Enter The Index To Remove An Element");
        Scanner S=new Scanner(System.in);
        index=S.nextInt();
        list.remove(index);
        System.out.println("The Element At The Index " +index +"Has Been Removed");

    }

    public void getchoice(){
        Menu M=new Menu();
        switch (choice){
        case 1:
            M.add();
            break;
        case 2:
            M.show();
            break;
        case 3:
            M.remove();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid Choice");
        }
    }

}
```

`Main Class`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]){
    Menu S = new Menu();
    S.greet();
    Scanner L=new Scanner(System.in);
    int y=0;
    do{
        S.choice();
        S.getchoice();
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue ?");
        System.out.println("Enter 1 to continue or 2 to exit");
        y=L.nextInt();
        }while(y==1);
    if(y==2){
        System.out.println("Exiting system...");
        System.out.println("GoodBye!");
    }

}

}
```

Here, indices 0 and 1 already contain 2 elements `Rahul` and `Sam` respectively. Now, when I run my program and select `Enter 1 To Add An Element` and input an element say `Sam`. Now, if I try to display the element selecting `Enter 2 To Display An Element` and then enter the index of the element as `0`, I should get the element `Rahul` instead I get is this :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at Menu.show(Menu.java:50)
at Menu.getchoice(Menu.java:72)
at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

The complete order of events at run time is given below :

```
Welcome!
Enter 1 To Add An Element
Enter 2 To Display An Element
Enter 3 To Delete An Element
1
Enter An Element
Sam
Do you want to continue ?
Enter 1 to continue or 2 to exit
1
Enter 1 To Add An Element
Enter 2 To Display An Element
Enter 3 To Delete An Element
2
Enter The Index
0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at Menu.show(Menu.java:50)
at Menu.getchoice(Menu.java:72)
at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger to check that the two elements you think are in the list actually are?  I doubt they are, as your `toList` method is never called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you execute `getchoice` method, you're always creating a new `Menu`. You shouldn't do that, and keep using the same instance of `Menu`.

Comment: @LancePreston If it works then please accept the answer to give credit.

Comment: I tried clicking the tick mark to accept the answer. It goes green for a while and again changes to white. I don't know that's wrong.

Comment: @Lance Preston You need to wait 15 minutes before accepting an answer. Have you tried after that time?